# Why should not we hang our ancestral (dead) photos near with God's photo?

Tags: gods, death

As a human, I feel that after dead my ancestral soul are bind with God. If so why can't I allow to hang their photos with the God's? Is it abnormal thing to do?

Comment: Do we have any proof of the hinduism to be said as you say?

Comment: But People today consider every of their ancestral as dead one who are abnormal of God whom we worship.

Comment: @Pratimaputra They believe that keeping dead photos near God may reduce the power or purity of him.

Comment: Because most people today are fallen from dharma. How do we keep Sri Rama's or Sri Krishna's images?Did they not leave their bodies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I heard some current guru asking not to keep departed parents' images in one's house, I could not believe my ears! It is so unfortunate for someone preaching Hinduism to say such a thing.

To a ward, parents and forefathers are gods.In fact the glory of mother is greater than heaven and this is well known. I hope the following quitations will make it clear that keeping their images is in fact encouraged. One of the nitya-karms or daily duties prescribed is pitri-tarpana as pitri-yajna, ie offering sacred water to the departed parents daily.So one must remember his departed parents regularly.Images also remind them.

Those who worship parents as gods have no need to worship any other gods. This was told by Bhishma to Yudisthira (in Santi-parva,Bhishma-Yudisthira-samvada,Rajadharmanushashana prakarana,chapter 18.

> Yudisthira asked Bhishma: O Bharata! Among the different branches of Dharma, which one do you think is the most followable?
>
> Bhishma said:Worshipping parents and the elder ones is the best Dharma...They are the three Vedas, they are the three Agnis. Just by serving them, one can win over the three worlds.In fact, their glory is more than that of Agni. All works of the ward who neglects his/her parents are fruitless. No one is more sinner than him who does not look after his parents.

Manu says

> One's father is the Garhapatya Agni and mother is the Dakshina Agni.Guru is Avahaniya Agni.One who serves these three adores all Dharmas.All works of him is fruitless who does not serve his parents and Acharya.(Chapter 2,slokas 225-237).

Kurma-Purana says

> Of all Gurus,the mother is the most worshipable. If parents are satisfied with the ward, all fruits of Dharma come to him or her automatically. So one must try his best to serve and satisfy them.(Uparibhaga, chapter 11).

In Vrihat-Dharma-purana, we get the Pitri-Stotra and Matri-Stotra for worshipping the parents.

The the Baudhayana Dharma Sutras say about the Pancha-Mahayajna (2.11.1-5):

> The following are five great yajnas [as part of regular duties]-- sacrifice to gods, **sacrifice to ancestors**, food sacrifice to beings, sacrifice to humans, and sacrifice to the Veda.

Katyayana-Smriti also prescribes the same duties:

> **One should know, as great yajnas, those that are performed successively daily for the Deities, the Spirits, the' departed Manes, for God(Brahman) and for mankind**.
>
> To deliver religious instructions, is the Brahmayajna ; **to offer watery** **oblations, is the Pitriyajna** ; to offer oblations of clarified butter to the Fire, is the Devayajna ; to offer Valis (offerings)) is the Bhutayajna ; and to treat guests, is the Nriyajna. (2 & 3, chapter 13)

As father is god, grand-father is god's god. I think it is clear from my answer that any ancestor's photo can be kept. And tarpana is offered to all the departed family members, at least for three generations to seven generation.Brahmaa is respected as He is the grand-father (pitAmaha) of the world.

(Reference: Srestha Dharma,Sitaramdas Omkarnath, Omkarnath Rachanavali, Mahamilan Math,Vol 6,page 114-125).

Comment: The above notes mainly highlights the importance of one's parents. Are you trying to highlight that everyone have to take care of their parents?I want to know about my grandfather's part in this. Please kindly provide us some notes about them in Hinduism.

Comment: As per the discussion, I get a point that everyone whom we worship/Consider as God, may be our grand elders.If so then we have all rights to hang our ancestors near to their ancestors(God).

Comment: I totally agree with the answer given by @Pratimaputra. Yes it is allowed since Parent's are also a form of God. You must have heard of Mata, Pita, Guru, Daivam all are one and the same. Furthermore I can confirm this in a realistic sense since : 1. We also place Picture of Sai Ram during Sai Bhajana who again was believed to be a form of God.

Comment: 2. I have seen at another place that the person holding the aarti event had placed his late Mother's picture beside Shiva's and the Pundit and various other people involved and attending it had no problem with it.
3. Idol and Picture worship of various G

Comment: Do Sreshtha Dharma, Omkar Rachanavali etc., say we should worship parents or directly put photos beside God? Same with Kurma Purana, Manu Smriti etc.,